# React Context changes not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have this component set up where I use the global context to keep track of my cart. However when the cartQty is updated I do not see the updated quantity on screen, only if I refresh the page.

```
const CartBody = () => {
  const { cart, setCart } = useGlobalContext();

  const increaseCartQty = (productName: any) => {
    const index = cart.findIndex((product) => product.name === productName);
    cart[index].quantity = cart[index].quantity + 1;
    setCart(cart);
  };

 return (<div>{cart.quantity}</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the state instead of creating a new one. When you set state in a function component, react does a `===` between the old state and the new state. If they're equal, it skips rendering.

Do this instead:

```
const increaseCartQty = (productName: any) => {
  const index = cart.findIndex((product) => product.name === productName);
  const newCart = [...cart];
  newCart[index] = {
    ...cart[index],
    quantity: cart[index].quantity + 1,
  };
  setCart(newCart);
};
```

Or:

```
const increaseCartQty = (productName: any) => {
  const newCart = cart.map((product) => {
    return product.name === productName
      ? {
          ...product,
          quantity: product.quantity + 1,
        }
      : product;
  });
  setCart(newCart);
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Only thing im wondering about is in my example; why did it update when I refresh?

Comment: The mutation of the state did happen, so if some external factor causes the component to render those changes will be part of the render output. It's just that the call to `setCart` won't trigger a rerender itself.